# How do I turn off suggestions to uninstall unused apps?

Tags: applications, settings

Google Play Store prompts me on a regular basis to uninstall unused apps. This prompt is a little bit dangerous because without much thinking, I could tap the confirmation dialogue and uninstall apps which I am using rarely, but do need. How do I turn off these suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the dialog is created by Google PlayStore? I only know such dialogs by pre-installed system-cleaner apps e.g. on LG or Sony devices.

Comment: This article says it's Google Play Store: https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/google-play-store-uninstall-unused-android-apps/

Comment: I've been looking for that one too and did not find a way to turn that notification off. At least, not yet. I'm on Android 12 and they tell me like once a week which is an incredible waste of my time.